# Why do we need the object sender as a parameter eventhandler in c#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know why we need the object sender as a parameter while we can pass it using the eventargs object like below:

```
SpecialEvent(this,new SpecialEventArgs(..));
void Func(object _sender,SpecialEventArgs _e){}
```

---

```
SpecialEvent(new SpecialEventArgs(this,..));
void Func(SpecialEventArgs _e){}
```

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you bind that event handler to multiple buttons?  It would be nice to see which button invoked the handler.  There is no value in moving this reference into the event args.

Comment: What about the value of not, having to declare everything with an extra parameter? instead all of my delegates now can take in a single parameter, less coding in general

Comment: thank you but I think we can use only eventhandler for that
"What if you bind that event handler to multiple buttons? It would be nice to see which button invoked the handler. "
Do you say that it can cause a problem if we don't use the object sender?
and use a class object reference as a field of eventargs? for example PanelClass rather than object ? so we don't need boxing unboxing

Comment: @johnny5 and having to check for a null event argument before referencing the sender negates that 'benefit'.  It also *requires* you create an event args object, something that isn't required now.  So, like I said, no value.

Comment: @Mahdi I didn't say that, no.  You are not required to use the sender parameter.  However, per the Framework Design Guidelines, section 5.4.1:  "DO use `object` as the type of the first parameter of the event handler, and call it `sender`.  DO use `EventArgs` or its subclass as the type of the second parameter."

Comment: @Mahdi You can see the real answer in Amy's last comment.  There is no good reason, people just do it because it's in the guidelines as what they should do, and they don't second-guess it.

Comment: @Mahdi boxing/unboxing is not relevant here unless you're passing value types.

Comment: It's worth noting that events can bubble, so conceivably the EventArgs could be passed over more than one hop but the sender could change each time. Embedding the sender in the EventArgs may therefore not be the most convenient option, especially if your EventArgs is immutable.